# Eclipse Error "build path contains duplicate entry"

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I am cloning a project with read permissions only.
After import, Eclipse will report an error saying

> build path contains duplicate entry

How can I disable this check?

Comment: Sounds like you need to report a bug to the project you're cloning.

Comment: I fact I had a previous installation of Eclipse, where this error hasn't been reported. So it must be configurable - somehow.